# How can I see how I earned reputation points?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, reputation

How can I see from who and from which questions I gained reputation points on **StackOverflow.com?**

I would like to see from which users and on which of my questions and answers I gained reputation points. And how many votes there are on my questions and answers, from other users.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot see from whom your reputation points have come from. You can, of course, see which posts of yours have provided reputation points; simply go to your profile.

Votes, and by extension the reputation points they provide, are anonymous.

Points for an accepted answer are obviously from the question asker. Points from bounties are from the person who posted the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

You can visit `/reputation/` on any site (make sure you are logged in!)

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation

However, votes are anonymous. You can only see on which questions and how much rep, not the user who voted one of your posts.